# Define pointer to array of int pointers in struct, how to access those ints?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have the following code:

```
struct demo{
    int *(*p)[];
};
int main() {
    struct demo *demo_ptr;
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;

    int *arr[2];
    arr[0] = &a;
    arr[1] = &b;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        printf("num in array = %d\n", *arr[i]);
    }

    demo_ptr->p = &arr;

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        printf("num in array = %d\n", demo_ptr->(*p)[i]);
    }

}
```

I'd like to access `a` and `b` by `demo_ptr`. But the code failed. How to assign value to `p` (a pointer to array of int pointers) declared in a struct, and how to access those ints in array through `demo_ptr`?

Comment: Why exactly do you need this pointer to array of pointers? This all seems needlessly complicated and for no obvious reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters you declared a pointer to an incomplete type

```
struct demo{
    int *(*p)[];
};
```

So you can not use the `sizeof` operator to determine the number of elements in the pointed array.

Secondly you defined an uninitialized pointer that has an indeterminate value.

```
struct demo *demo_ptr;
```

So again dereferencing this pointer invokes undefined behavior.

You should write for example

```
struct demo{
    int *(*p)[2];
};
```

and in main

```
struct demo demo;
//...
demo.p = &arr;

for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( *demo.p ) / sizeof( **demo.p ); i++ )
{
    printf( "num in array = %d\n", *( *demo.p )[i]);
}
```

Comment: @EricPostpischil You may not use it in the subscript operator.

Answer (score 1):

Try: `*(*demo_ptr->p)[i]`.

The problem was that sub-scripting operator `[]` has higher priority than dereference operator `*`. This can be fixed by placing parenthesis around `*demo_ptr->p`.

Other issue is that `demo_ptr` points to no object. Initialize it with:

```
struct demo *demo_ptr = malloc(sizeof *demo_ptr);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following:

```
struct demo{
    int *(*p)[];
};
```

the member `p` is a pointer to an incomplete array type. The array type is incomplete because no length has been specified. The array element type is `int *`.

The incomplete array type is not very useful. In my opinion, if the length is not fixed, it would be better to define `p` as a pointer to pointer to `int`:

```
struct demo{
    int **p;
};
```

Then, in `main():`

```
    demo_ptr->p = arr;

    /* assuming arr[0] and arr[1] are valid pointers to int: */
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        printf("num in array = %d\n", *demo_ptr->p[i]);
    }
```

(Note: `*demo_ptr->p[i]` is equivalent to `*((demo_ptr->p)[i])`.)

The other problem in `main()` is that `demo_ptr` is an uninitialized pointer, so the dereferences above result in *undefined behavior*. It needs to point to a `struct demo` or to allocated storage with size at least `sizeof (struct demo)`. For example:

```
    struct demo *demo_ptr;
    struct demo demo;

    demo_ptr = &demo;
```